# How to set max content-length of post http in SpringBoot / AWS EC2?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I am trying to do a http post with a high content length. This is possible when I am working in local (Tomcat server embedded in Spring). But when I try to do the post when the app is deployed (in AWS), it is not possible due to content-length.

I would like to set the maximum of the content-length in Spring .yml for AWS. Maybe there are another solution.

Could you help me?

Thank you so much.